# Encoding::UndefinedConversionError from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 in sinatra 2

Tags: ruby, encoding, localization, internationalization, sinatra

iam working on a large app built with sinatra 1.2, few days ago i upgraded sinatra gem to version 2.
after upgrading this error produce

`Encoding::UndefinedConversionError - "\xD8" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8:`
when pass param with arabic language like `services/مواقع`

i searched for it and i didn't found any soluation except `force_encoding("UTF-8")` that can't use it for all params in my app

can anyone help me on this? Thank you!

Comment: It looks as if the encoding for your Arabic might be something other than ASCII-8BIT. Could it possibly be in an Arabic text specific encoding such as ASMO-449?

Comment: [This](https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/issues/1434) could help ... oh wait ;-)

Comment: It's quite a huge leap from version 1.2 to version 2.0. Did you jump right to 2.0 or did you upgrade incrementally? An incremental upgrade could help to narrow down the problem.

Answer (score 0):

`force_encoding("utf-8")` was the solution for me